# Auto Filled Custom Menus for Custom Post Types?

Tags: menus

Is there anyway to have custom menus that fill out automatically, specifically for custom post types?

You can do it for default pages but nothing else it seems...

For example you have a page which needs to list a range of projects in a navigation.

You could do it with a query for that specific custom post type so all new posts are added automatically but what about the wp_menu class's that are added?

So basically can you have a list navigation which populates automatically with the wp_menu classes e.g current-menu-item

Because having to add them in the menu area in the admin is a bit clunky.

This possible, or not yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do, but I'll just take a shot in the dark.

Try messing around with `custom fields`. You could have a custom field with a boolean value. Then in your template, you would check to see if the post has that value. So if that value returns `true`, have your template do whatever you're trying to do.

Not sure if this helps any, try clarifying a bit.

Comment: It looks to me that you are missing the shot... IMO, the first and penultimate paragraphs define the core of the question...

Comment: Yes sorry, a custom menu that fills its self out automatically, so you have all the function of the custom menu but with any post type. It does it for pages automatically, if you click the little check box.

Comment: This is basically what i mean, but looks like its not doable :( http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/automatically-add-new-custom-posts-to-a-submenu-within-a-wp-30-menu